# Iphone send data over a local network between two iphones

Tags: iphone, networking

i'm developing an app to exchange data between two iphone's connected to the same local network but i don't know where to start.

Anyone can show me and example in order to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: It might be helpful to add a broad brush description of the app and kind, volume and purpose of the data you are wanting to send as there would be a number of options each with their own suitability criteria.

Comment: i want only to send a string from one devide to other devide... it's all i need. can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at peer to peer connectivity in Game Kit and decide whether this is what you need.

Alternatively, Bonjour API and standard network programming is available.

Comment: i want only to send a string.. so.. is there any example similar to this?

Comment: Still, even for only sending a string you'll need to find out where to send the string to. This is where Bonjour or GameKit come into play. If you have little or no experience with network programming, probably GameKit is a good start. I don't have reference to a good example, please check google or the WWDC session videos.